# stop a jquery animation loop (function and nested)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would i stop a jquery animation from loading upon user interaction?

```
    $('#jqNav li a').click(function(){

    if($(this).parent().is(".nav1")){ $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({ "background-position" : "0 -50px" });} 
    else if($(this).parent().is(".nav2")) { $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({ "background-position" : "0 -100px" });}
    else if($(this).parent().is(".nav3")) { $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({ "background-position" : "0 -150px" });}
    else if($(this).parent().is(".nav4")) { $('.landing .main .nav ul').css({ "background-position" : "0 -200px" });};

    $page = $(this).attr('href');
    var $hashTag = $(this).attr('name');
    window.location = "#" + $hashTag;
    loadData();
    return false;
});
```

this is the user click function;

```
    function doReplay(){
    $('body')
    .fadeTo(0,1,function(){
        $page = $welcome;
        loadData();

    })
    .delay(1000)
    .fadeTo(0,1,function(){
        $page = $startup;
        loadData();
    })
    .delay(1000)
    .fadeTo(0,1,function(){
        $page = $to2m;
        loadData();
    })
    .delay(1000)
    .fadeTo(0,1, function(){
        $page = $to25m;
        loadData();
        setTimeout(function(){doReplay();},5000);
    });
}
```

and the above is the animation function

I have tried clearTimeout but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want the animation function to not fire after the click function has been executed?

Comment: @Jivings that is correct

Comment: Where is doReplay being called from?

Comment: @Jivings it's called on document ready

Comment: So the onClick changes the window.location, and doReplay is called after the change. But you only want it to be called if the page has loaded from something other than the onClick?

Comment: @Jivings well i only want this animation to trigger on loading of the first page, when a user clicks the window.location is changed with a hash tag (#welcome) which also allows bookmarking.

But your suggestion should do what i want it to, (with some tweaks to allow for hash recognition)

Comment: Yes, I would suggest checking for that hashtag. That's the only variable that you will have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var stopAnim;
$('#jqNav li a').click(function(){
     ...

     stopAnim = true;
}

function doReplay(){

     if(!stopAnim){
         // do animation
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a boolean value that you would check in your animation method.

```
if (!stopAnim) { setTimeout(function(){doReplay();},5000); }
```

Comment: could you add some more context to your answer i tried replacing my original settimeout with your code and added a global variable in document ready and a stopAni = true; in my click function

Comment: If you read the comments, the page is being reloaded, so no persistent variable.

Comment: @Jivings the page itself is not reloading i am using .load() to load div's into the page

Comment: Oh, in that case this is a fine and easy way of doing it.